# Is backend_address_pool_id argument or frontend port range not supported in azurerm_lb_nat_rule in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm quite new to terraform, and i've been trying to deploy 2 VMs behind a LB.
I keep receiving the following error when deploying the resources (mind you, everything else gets deployed as expected, just the rule does not):

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 119, in resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "example1":
│  119:   frontend_port_start            = 5000
│
│ An argument named "frontend_port_start" is not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 120, in resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "example1":
│  120:   frontend_port_end              = 5100
│
│ An argument named "frontend_port_end" is not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 122, in resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "example1":
│  122:   backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.example.id
│
│ An argument named "backend_address_pool_id" is not expected here.
╵
```

This is the resource in question:

```
resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "example1" {
  resource_group_name            = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name                           = "SSHAccess"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port_start            = 5000
  frontend_port_end              = 5100
  backend_port                   = 1234
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.example.id
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "PublicIPAddress"
}
```

LB SKU is Standard:

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  name                = "TestLoadBalancer"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Standard"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "PublicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
}
```

According to the documentation they are supported arguments:
[https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/lb_nat_rule#backend_address_pool_id](https://stackoverflow.com)

In the meanwhile i've found a better method of doing what i needed, but still could not figure out why the error above is happening.

I searched a bit, and could not find why this happens.

Any idea?

This will deploy the rule, but will not be attached to anything the the backend pool/individual VM

```
resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "example1" {
  resource_group_name            = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name                           = "SSHAccess"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 5000
  backend_port                   = 22
#  backend_address_pool_ids = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.example.id
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "PublicIPAddress"
}
```

Comment: May I know which version of the provider you're using? The backend_address_pool_id argument for the azurerm_lb_nat_rule resource was introduced in version 2.70.0 of the Azure provider for Terraform.

Comment: I am using version 3.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to Provision the backend_address_pool_id argument or frontend port range it supported in azurerm_lb_nat_rule in terraform successfully.

Looking at your code and comparing it with the documentation, it seems that the `frontend_port_start`, `frontend_port_end`, and `backend_address_pool_id` arguments are indeed supported in the current version of the AzureRM Terraform provider.

Since the provider information was provided as **3.0.0**. I suggest you update to the latest one as it seems to be working fine as far as I am concerned.

To resolve this issue, please use a version of the AzureRM Terraform provider that supports these arguments. You can specify the provider version in your configuration to ensure you use a compatible version.

Here to have a smooth transition I was using the latest version of the provider to avoid unnecessary errors.

**My terraform Configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
} # Here I used provider module configuration with the latest version i.e..,v3.71.0

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
    name = "v-bolliv"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "example-public-ipvk"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  name                = "TestLoadBalancervk"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Standard"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "PublicIPAddressvk"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "example" {
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name                = "example-backend-poolvk"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_nat_rule" "example1" {
  resource_group_name            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name                           = "SSHAccessvk"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port_start            = 5000
  frontend_port_end              = 5100
  backend_port                   = 1234
  backend_address_pool_id        = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.example.id
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "PublicIPAddressvk"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vnetvk"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "example-subnetvk"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nicvk"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "example-ipconfigvk"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                  = "example-vmvk"
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.example.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "example-osdisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "example-vm"
    admin_username = "adminuser"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Yes, you are right, on 3.69.0 (latest one at the moment) it's working fine. Thank you.